# Does PDF preview and export in Careers support Unicode?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, unicode, pdf

It looks like Unicode range for Gujarati is not supported. When I import projects from Github which has Gujarati text as main project description, the text appears as '?' characters. Are other unicode character ranges supported?

Comment: It looks like this problem is not limited to the PDF, it shows the ??? on your regular profile too. It's in the GitHub repo description. I changed one of my repo's to use your description and it seemed to work. 

Try removing those projects from your profile and re-importing?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a GitHub API specific issue that comes up after a day or two after importation. I've tested this out with Traditional Chinese throughout my profile and it seems to be specific to this one section (both in the profile and in the PDF). I'll bring this up with the other devs to see how we can get it fixed.

Comment: Does GitHub's API not support the latest Unicode yet?

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed.

Non-latin descriptions are now fully supported for Github projects in profiles. The PDF preview also benefits from this fix.

Thank you for your report !